# How can I implement dynamic filtering purely with AJAX and still keep a usable history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filtering

I'm trying to implement AJAX filtering on my own e-commerce website and looking for the best solution.

With what I've come up is:

Making all content statically generated (built by server-side and then calling ajax request on the same page but with parameters). The only cons is that user doesn't have any back history as his URL page doesn't change.

I would try to implement history.api and etc but just saw this awesome filtering right here: [http://trendygolf.com/shop?brand[]=15&brand[]=27&price-min=0&pricemax=2000&sort=newest](http://trendygolf.com/shop?brand%5B%5D=15&brand%5B%5D=27&price-min=0&pricemax=2000&sort=newest)

From what I see it makes AJAX calls AND changes the URL without reloading the page, how is that even possible?

And of course it simply replaces the old html page with the new one from request

I would love to hear some help on this one, what are best practices, pros/cons, and how does trendygolf.com make it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use the [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) library, which lets you change the browser's state/URL from JavaScript. Basically this library uses the HTML5 History API if available, but can emulate it in browsers which don't support this. History.js is a low-level API though, and you may want to use a Router abstraction on top of it, which simplifies your programming considerably. For this purpose I've implemented the [StateRouter.js](https://github.com/aknuds1/staterouter.js) library.

A simple example of how one may use StateRouter.js:

```
function getHome() {
}
function getPersons() {
}
function getPerson(id) {
}

var router = new staterouter.Router();
// Configure routes
router
  .route('/', getHome)
  .route('/persons', getPersons)
  .route('/persons/:id', getPerson);

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Perform initial routing
    router.perform();

    // Navigate to a URL
    router.navigate('/persons/1');

    // Go back
    router.back();

    // Go forward
    router.go(1);
});
```

Comment: Looks legit!
Thanks man, will dig into it ;)
Talking about support of history.js, what behavior will be seen in IE8 for example?

Comment: @Leg0 I haven't tested History.js with an older browser, but from its documentation I would think it'd fall back to relying on URL hashes. See e.g. https://github.com/balupton/History.js/#how-would-they-look-in-a-html4-browser.

Comment: @Leg0 Note that StateRouter.js is still in early stages of development, and specifically it's pretty limited in how much of History.js it exposes. If you find it lacking, I'd love some feedback :)

Comment: Hey man, does your router support request params?
I see it can handle /:id, but how about ?paramId=id

Comment: @Leg0 It doesn't do anything with params. Are you experiencing that URLs with params don't get routed?

Comment: @Leg0 I've updated the project [README](https://github.com/aknuds1/staterouter.js#usage) to show an example of routing a URL with a query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to updating the URL in place, it's part of HTML5, not 100% sure how IE support is though. This will work:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

To learn more about this sort of the thing check out the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the answer given by newmu
when you need to maintain history/state on ajax calls you should use `hashtags`
which are a part of the url after symbol hash('#'). whatever you write after `#` in a url isn't sent to the server
in browsers where history api is still not supported hashtags are used to maintain state
also hashtags can be changed without reloading the page

Comment: but hashtags are not sent to server and in case if user copies the current link or saves it in favorites - it automatically loses current state after opening this link again
Which is definately a minus

Comment: @Leg0 - hashtags are used with javascript and are read at page load and the proper action is taken after that.